# Indexing multiple tables data in solr

Tags: mysql, solr

I am currently using Solr search to index my DB tables data. For one entity it is working fine but when I am trying to get data from multiple tables I am unable to index them can someone help me with this

My `data-config.xml` is as below

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="data_source_0" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/akresidential_saya" user="root" password="gaian"/>
<document>             
 <entity name="events" 
                datasource="data_source_0" 
                pk="eveID"
                query="select eveID,name,type from events"
               >
         <field column="name" name="name"/>
            <field column="type" name="type"/>
            <field column="eveID" name="eveID"/>
          </entity>


    <entity name="publishers" 
        datasource="data_source_0" 
        pk="id"
        query="select name,cat,id,domain from publishers"
       >
       <field column="name" name="name"/>
        <field column="cat" name="cat"/>
        <field column="id" name="id"/>
    <field column="domain" name="domain"/>
      </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

Since I am new to Solr I am unable to define my `schema.xml` so that I can index the above two tables data separately, and also those two tables should be in same core

Previously I searched about this and got few examples when I tried them it not gone quite well. So I need sample `schema.xml` based on my above two tables file so that I can fulfill my requirements

EDITED:
when I done full data import on events table I got like this[image] 
but when I started full data import for my publisher's table I got like this [image]

it fetched record but not added as document in Solr
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "not working"? What do you expect to happen and what actually happen?

Comment: please see edited question

Comment: It does not look like it found any records in the database for that second query. I would manually confirm that they exist first before focusing on DIH. And the issue seems to be around that second table, not about multiple of them, based on your description.

Comment: its not a problem with my db i inserted a record in my second tabe

Comment: @RaviTeja, did you resolve problem? I have the same one :(

Comment: @KostyaVyrodov I solved this problem temporarily, but i think it is not recommended way. If you want i can share